# Removing a line feed from the header in of a c# web request

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, http-headers

I need to remove the last line feed from a http webrequest in order to communicate with an json-rpc service. 
The request which .net generates looks like this.

```
POST http://localhost.:8332/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.1)
Authorization: Basic dGlwa2c6dGlwa2c=
Host: localhost.:8332
Content-Length: 42
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

{"id":1,"method":"getinfo","params":[]}
```

What I would need would be this (notice the missing line feed after last header value and the begin of the json content):

```
POST http://localhost.:8332/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; MS Web Services Client Protocol 4.0.30319.1)
Authorization: Basic dGlwa2c6dGlwa2c=
Host: localhost.:8332
Content-Length: 42
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive
{"id":1,"method":"getinfo","params":[]}
```

I can't find anything where I could manipulate the header which is actually sent to service.

See http://www.bitcoin.org/smf/index.php?topic=2170.0 for more background on the problem...

Comment: If the service needs the request like your second example then it's not valid HTTP.  HTTP requires a blank line separating the headers from the body (if any).

Comment: Have you tested this and verified that it works without the newline? To test this you can use telnet (run telnet hostname 80, then past in your request from a text editor). I've never heard of a web server that cared about about \r\n or \n, so hopefully that won't make any difference. If it does you can use a the NetworkStream class to be very deliberate about exactly what characters you send.

Comment: Also, your HTTP request looks invalid because it should just have a path after the POST verb, instead of a full URL (i.e. / instead of http://localhost.:8332/). But maybe that just fiddler.

Comment: I've tested it with fiddler. when i remove the newline it works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally resolved my (core) issue. the problem with my communication with the rpc service, was that I had not set content-type. The service was requiring a content-type of "application/json-rpc" to work properly.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Sounded like a really weird and frustrating bug.